# Trying to create a control panel (radius, upper percentile...) for deckgl hexagon layer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deck.gl, kepler.gl

Im using the hexagon layer example from deck.gl as my base and trying to find a way to include a control panel similar to their online website https://deck.gl/examples/hexagon-layer/

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {StaticMap} from 'react-map-gl';
import {AmbientLight, PointLight, LightingEffect} from '@deck.gl/core';
import {HexagonLayer} from '@deck.gl/aggregation-layers';
import DeckGL from '@deck.gl/react';
import {Controller} from 'deck.gl';

// Source data CSV
const DATA_URL =
  'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/visgl/deck.gl-data/master/examples/3d-heatmap/heatmap-data.csv'; // eslint-disable-line

const ambientLight = new AmbientLight({
  color: [255, 255, 255],
  intensity: 1.0
});

const pointLight1 = new PointLight({
  color: [255, 255, 255],
  intensity: 0.8,
  position: [-0.144528, 49.739968, 80000]
});

const pointLight2 = new PointLight({
  color: [255, 255, 255],
  intensity: 0.8,
  position: [-3.807751, 54.104682, 8000]
});

const lightingEffect = new LightingEffect({ambientLight, pointLight1, pointLight2});

const OPTIONS = ['radius', 'coverage', 'upperPercentile'];

const material = {
  ambient: 0.64,
  diffuse: 0.6,
  shininess: 32,
  specularColor: [51, 51, 51]
};

const INITIAL_VIEW_STATE = {
  longitude: -1.415727,
  latitude: 52.232395,
  zoom: 6.6,
  minZoom: 5,
  maxZoom: 15,
  pitch: 40.5,
  bearing: -27
};

const MAP_STYLE = 'https://basemaps.cartocdn.com/gl/dark-matter-nolabels-gl-style/style.json';

export const colorRange = [
  [1, 152, 189],
  [73, 227, 206],
  [216, 254, 181],
  [254, 237, 177],
  [254, 173, 84],
  [209, 55, 78]
];

OPTIONS.forEach(key => {
  document.getElementById(key).oninput = renderLayer;
});

renderLayer();

function renderLayer () {
  const options = {};
  OPTIONS.forEach(key => {
    const value = +document.getElementById(key).value;
    document.getElementById(key + '-value').innerHTML = value;
    options[key] = value;
  });
function getTooltip({object}) {
  if (!object) {
    return null;
  }
  const lat = object.position[1];
  const lng = object.position[0];
  const count = object.points.length;

  return `\
    latitude: ${Number.isFinite(lat) ? lat.toFixed(6) : ''}
    longitude: ${Number.isFinite(lng) ? lng.toFixed(6) : ''}
    ${count} Accidents`;
}

/* eslint-disable react/no-deprecated */
export default function App({
  data,
  mapStyle = MAP_STYLE,
  radius = 1000,
  upperPercentile = 100,
  coverage = 1
}) {
  const layers = [
    new HexagonLayer({
      id: 'heatmap',
      colorRange,
      data,
      elevationRange: [0, 3000],
      elevationScale: data && data.length ? 50 : 0,
      extruded: true,
      getPosition: d => d,
      pickable: true,
      material,
      coverage,
      radius,
      upperPercentile,
      transitions: {
        elevationScale: 3000
      }
    })
  ];

  return (
    <DeckGL
      layers={layers}
      effects={[lightingEffect]}
      initialViewState={INITIAL_VIEW_STATE}
      controller={true}
      getTooltip={getTooltip}
    >
      <StaticMap reuseMaps mapStyle={mapStyle} preventStyleDiffing={true}/>
    </DeckGL>
  );
}

export function renderToDOM(container) {
  render(<App />, container);

  require('d3-request').csv(DATA_URL, (error, response) => {
    if (!error) {
      const data = response.map(d => [Number(d.lng), Number(d.lat)]);
      render(<App data={data} />, container);
    }
  });
}
```

[This is what the happens if i run the example code without the control panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmEq9.png)

[This is the what loads when i run the current code (example with my additions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9snp.png)

I am new to javascript,
so any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add `mapboxApiAccessToken` to your `StaticMap` component because `react-map-gl` is a Mapbox map library for React js.

```js
const MAPBOX_TOKEN = '...'

// some code here

return(
    // some code here
    <StaticMap 
        reuseMaps 
        mapStyle={mapStyle} 
        preventStyleDiffing={true}
        mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN}
    />
    // some code here
)
```

You can get the value of Mapbox token from here https://account.mapbox.com/access-tokens/